# Is there is any example of continuous bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ which attains 'either' maximum 'or' minimum on $\mathbb{R}$ but not both.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to find example of continuous bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ which attains 'either' maximum 'or' minimum on $\mathbb{R}$ but not both.

**My attempt**:

First of all, is such function exists? (How)? If it exists then isn't it will contradict extreme value theorem?

Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ works?

Comment: The definition I am used to insists that the maximum and minimum are attained.  In that case the question does not make sense.  If you don't insist they be attained, like sup and inf, your example is a good one.

Comment: @RossMillikan sir, in first case how question does not make sense?

Comment: You ask that one of the maximum and minimum not be attained, but the definition of those terms says that they are attained.  Your function has a maximum of $1$ at $x=0$ but it has no minimum.  The inf is $0$, but there is no $x$ that makes $f(x)=0$

Comment: @RossMillikan sir how they are attained (by definition)? Didn't get it.

Comment: The definition of maximum that I am familiar with says that it is the value of the function that is greater than or equal to all the other values of the function.  It requires that the maximum be the value of the function at some point in the domain.

Comment: I think there's no problem with your question, despite @Ross's protestation. The function does not attain a minimum value. To answer your question, the Extreme Value Theorem requires that the domain be a *closed interval*.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I was reading "attains either its maximum or minimum" to guarantee that there was a maximum and minimum.  You are reading it to say there might not be a minimum to attain.  I can see that as an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$. Then $f$ is continuous and bounded. Its maximum value $1$ is attined but its infimum  $0$ is not attained.

Comment: Sir, please can you provide, an example which has minimum value but  not maximum value?

Comment: Just take $-f$ where $f$ is the function I have defined. @AkashPatalwanshi

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment your example works if you replace maximum/minimum by supremum/infimum.

Otherwise, consider $f(x)=|x|.$ It achieves its minimum on $\mathbb{R}$ but the maximum does not exist. Similarly, $g(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ achieves its maximum on $\mathbb{R}$ but does not achieve the infimum (minimum, of course, does not exist).

If you say that the 'maximum' and 'minimum' should exist, then your question does not make sense. Because maximum/minimum is by definition achieved by the function,

Comment: Are example in your answer, are bounded function in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $f$ is not bounded. You can replace it with $(-g).$